# How to create an area with various 'pages'?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

The easiest way to explain what I'm trying to do would be to think of of it as starting off and seeing the content displayed in the desired area. The user clicks on a next button and it replaces the previous content with the next content. It goes on in a similar manner, sort of like a visual novel, but not really?

The only problem is, I can't figure out the best way to get it to erase the previous content and add the next content.

I'm hoping to do this with JavaScript or other derivatives, since I'm more familiar with it, but I'd be willing to work with any web integrated language.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is called `pagination`. Search for it on Google and you will find many solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client side language for modifying the current page will be javascript.  There are no other cross-browser choices if you're going to change the page client-side without loading a whole new page from the server each time.

Here are some of the possibilities with javascript:

1. Have all the content present in the original page and just hide/show blocks of content as each successive button is pressed.
2. Load dynamic content from your server with ajax and remove old content as the new content is loaded by Ajax and inserted into the page.
3. Use an iframe and programmatically change the `.src` property on the iframe to successively load new content.

Option 1 is the easiest if there isn't too much content to all fit in the main page.  Blocks of content can easily be hidden by setting `obj.style.display = "none"` or shown with the reverse `obj.style.display = "block"`.

Option 2 is a bit more involved as you need to be able to make AJAX calls to your server to load the desired content and then it needs to be inserted into the page as the old content is removed.  With a library like jQuery, this is a bit easier for the less experienced programmer.

Option 3 is also pretty easy to do, but not as flexible since iframes don't automatically conform to the height of your content like a `<div>` does, but they have the advantage that each successive content can just be a whole mini HTML page on your server.

---

Here's a working example of option 1 where the content is hidden/shown using plain javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/6ZFUq/

This example uses some CSS rules that trigger off a class name and then a class name is added or removed from a block of content to make that block show or hide.

HTML:

```
<button id="next">Next</button><br><br>

<div class="content active">Content 1</div>
<div class="content">Content 2</div>
<div class="content">Content 3</div>
<div class="content">Content 4</div>
<div class="content">Content 5</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* hide all content blocks by default */
.content {
    display: none;
}

.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript (located right before the `</body>` tag):

```
// utility functions
function removeClass(elem, cls) {
    var str = " " + elem.className + " ";
    elem.className = str.replace(" " + cls + " ", " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function addClass(elem, cls) {
    elem.className += (" " + cls);
}


// install event handler on Next button
document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // get active page
    var active = document.querySelectorAll(".content.active")[0];
    var all = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
    // find the active one in the list
    var activeIndex;
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        if (all[i] === active) {
            activeIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    // show the next one (wrapping back around if necessary)
    var nextItem = all[(activeIndex + 1) % all.length];
    addClass(nextItem, "active");
    // hide the previous one
    removeClass(active, "active");
});
```

---

To show you the benefits of using a library like jQuery, here's the same functionality in jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ts8Bz/

```
// install event handler on Next button
$("#next").click(function() {
    var next = $(".content.active").removeClass("active").next();
    if (next.length) {
        next.addClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".content").eq(0).addClass("active");
    }
});
```